# Entity framework fluent api 1:1 property on AspNetUser to other table cannot change Account_Id property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I am working with the fluent api to setup the relationships for my entity database. I have the typical AspNetUsers table, this table has a column called Id (String) which is the primary key for the table. I extended IdentityUser and gave it other properties, 2 such properties are AdvisorProfile, and StudentProfile.

ApplicationUser has optional AdvisorProfile and StudentProfile.
AdvsiorProfile and StudentProfile have required Account (ApplicationUser).

My problem, when the tables generate AdvisorProfile has a property called Account_Id, which is the link back to ApplicationUser in AspNetUser's table. I want to change that naming convention but my fluent api code doesn't seem to be making a difference.

Fluent Api for Account -> Advisor / Account foreign key naming

```
//Advisor Profile to Login Account
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasOptional(x => x.AdvisorProfile).WithRequired(x => x.Account).Map(x => x.MapKey("AdvisorFK"));
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasOptional(x => x.AdvisorProfile).WithRequired(x => x.Account).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<Advisor>().HasRequired<ApplicationUser>(x => x.Account).WithOptional(x => x.AdvisorProfile).Map(x => x.MapKey("AccountFK"));
modelBuilder.Entity<Advisor>().HasRequired<ApplicationUser>(x => x.Account).WithOptional(x => x.AdvisorProfile).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Table Generation Code:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.Advisors",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true),
            FirsName = c.String(),
            LastName = c.String(),
            MiddleName = c.String(),
            Email = c.String(),
            PhoneNumber = c.String(),
            PrimaryContact = c.Int(nullable: false),
            Account_Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.Account_Id) //Here is the issue
                .Index(t => t.Account_Id);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you use multiple fluent configurations for one and the same relationship, which is error prone and hard to say which one actually applies.

As a rule of thumb, always use single fluent mapping per relationship. In your case, it should be something like this:

```
//Advisor Profile to Login Account
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
    .HasOptional(x => x.AdvisorProfile)             
    .WithRequired(x => x.Account)
    .Map(x => x.MapKey("AdvisorFK"))
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```